# Push all data of Array of Strings into new array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a array of string Like this:

```
    Array[6] =  ",e1,e2,e3"
    Array[7]=  ",d1,d2"
    Array=[8]  ",c1,c2,c3,c4"
```

Mean 6th index of array have 3 strings with comma seperated . I now I want it to be like

```
newarray[



    Array[6]=   "e1"
    Array[7]=  "e2"
    Array[8]=   "e3"
    Array[9]=   "d1"
    Array[10]   "d2"
```

and so on
    ]

Forget about 1st let me tell you all in easy way. On array index 1 I have 1 string with ',' separated 3 sub string . Now I want to push all three sub string into index and all three substrings must be separately in array

Comment: Please show up the whole string array, your example makes no sense!

Comment: Can you better explain the rules? What happens if `9` has completely different values? Make sure you have a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: @evolutionxbox   sorry actually I pressed shift  before posting so mess created. I fixed now .

Comment: @Teemu sorry now check

Comment: @eisbehr now check plz

Comment: You cant' have an `array` with duplicate keys.

Comment: @F128115 the output array is invalid. Array's IDs are unique.

Comment: @evolutionxbox now check

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ sorry now check

Comment: `[].concat.apply([], arr.map(i => i.split(','))).filter(i => i !=='')`

Comment: @eisbehr kindly post again that code it worked :D

Comment: Okay, it's back. @F128115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you correctly, you want the data to be split and ordered in an new array. Hope this example helps you:

```js
var newarr = [];
var arr = [
  ",e1,e2,e3",
  ",d1,d2",
  ",c1,c2,c3,c4"
];


for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    newarr = [].concat(newarr, arr[i].replace(",", "").split(","))
}

console.log(newarr);
```

Comment: The concat invocation is throwing an error... not sure why. Maybe use `[]` instead.

Comment: Fixed @evolutionxbox

Comment: Array.concat is not a function",  I am getting this error

Comment: @eisbehr  its giving me array of length '2097151'  . so so much data

Comment: Could you check if this still produce such strage output for you? @F128115

Comment: @eisbehr thank you  but let me verify 1,2 entries are repeating .let me check

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using map-reduce.

```js
var arr = [
    ",e1,e2,e3",
    ",d1,d2",
    ",c1,c2,c3,c4"
];

var newarr = arr.map(item => item.replace(",", "").split(","))
                .reduce((acc, item) => acc.concat(item), [])
                .map(item => [item]);

console.log(newarr);
```

To avoid the last `map` you may change the `reduce` to the following, however the version above seems semantically pleasing :) However, use whatever fits for you.

```
.reduce((acc, item) => {
    item.forEach(val => acc.push(val));
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Why not make use of ES6 spread operator.

```js
const arr = [['1','2','3'],['1','2']];
const newArr = arr.reduce((init,next) => {
   return init = [...init,...next];
},[]);
console.log('arr:',arr);
console.log('newArray:',newArr);
```